# Large stack size in Mac application

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a cocoa application running on Mac OS 10.8.2. After running for 10 hrs, its memory usage increases considerably. I checked using `Instruments` tool, but no memory leaks are observed. When I analyze the VM allocations, it shows me that 50% of the memory is consumed by stack pages. It contains around 10K stack pages, which is weird. I have around 17 threads, but they are not created or destroyed during the execution. They are just setup initially.
I am sure that this increased stack size is problem, but I am clueless on how to analyze it further. `Instruments` tool does not give an idea of who allocated those stack pages.

Please help me. Any hints are much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest artificially limiting the stack size and waiting for a stack overflow. Likely culprit is a data structure processed by a recursive function. The structure grows over time, but does not leak. As it grows, the recursion goes deeper and deeper.

Comment: But I gathered the process sample, and it does not show large stack depth for any thread. And, also none of the function is recursive. However, I have a thread which has indefinite while loop which breaks only when user exits the application. Can it case a problem?

Comment: The recursive function doesn't need to be executing for a long time. Even a brief, large allocation will cause the memory to remain allocated. The culprit could be part of a framework or library, not your own. It's not clear that a real problem exists, but what you've seen sounds like a red flag.